# Get text from combobox in selected tab

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tabcontrol

[image: Form]

In all of these tabs, I have a combobox with different functions as strings. I want the text under Preview (it's a richtextbox with "Nothing is selected." as a default string) to change whenever I select an item in each of the different tabs' comboboxes. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried

Comment: Do you want the richtextbox to show the string from just one combo or do you want to concatenate the text from the different combos?

Comment: Use the `_onChanged` events of the comboboxes, and change text to selected item when event is fired.

Comment: @Steve I want the RTB to show the exact string that is in the currently selected combobox.selectedindex (i.e. BENCHMARK_CAPTION...) and when I change the tab and select the element in the other tab's combobox, the text in the RTB should change again to the currently selected.

Comment: @ElectricRouge I was thinking of doing a very large switch/case or if (or something of the sort), because my c# knowledge is limited, but I thought there must be a better way to do what I was planning.

Comment: Your combo allows the user to type in the edit portion (if I see your picture correctly) so the user could start typing something and what happen in this case to your RTB?

Comment: @Steve the combo's items are populated via an XML, you can't type anything - they are read-only and predetermined, so you can only select them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set every TextChanged event of all of your combobox to the same event handler

```
 comboBox1.TextChanged += CommonComboTextChanged;
 comboBox2.TextChanged += CommonComboTextChanged;
 comboBox3.TextChanged += CommonComboTextChanged;
 comboBox4.TextChanged += CommonComboTextChanged;


private void CommonComboTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cbo = sender as ComboBox;
    richTextBox.Text = cbo.Text;
}
```

However, if you change the DropDownStyle of your combos to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList then you could use the SelectedIndexChanged event that will be triggered only when your user changes the item selected by using the DropDown List.

```
 comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonComboIndexChanged;
 comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonComboIndexChanged;;
 comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonComboIndexChanged;;
 comboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonComboIndexChanged;;


 private void CommonComboIndexChanged;(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ComboBox cbo = sender as ComboBox;
    richTextBox.Text = cbo.Text;
 }
```

Finally to set the content of the RTB to the one of the combo in the current tab page you need to handle the TabChanged event of your tabControl

```
 private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) 
 {
     switch(e.TabPageIndex)
     {
         case 0:
            richTextBox.Text = comboBox1.Text;            
            break;
         // so on for the other page and combos
     }
 }
```

Or if your comboboxes share a common initial part of their names

```
 private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) 
 {
    var result = e.TabPage.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("cboFunction"));
    if(result != null)
    {
        ComboBox b = result.ToList().First();
        richTextBox.Text = comboBox1.Text;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was hoping for something along these lines. I'll give it a try and report with the eventual results :)

Oh... so I won't be able to pass without a switch/case after all :/ I was hoping for some way to dynamically get the currently selected combobox index's value and put it as the rtb's text.

Comment: Is it possible to access (on SelectedIndex Changed) TabControl->SelectedTab->Child(ComboBox).SelectedIndex.Value (or something along these lines)?

Comment: I was able to avoid the last part (the one with the switch/case). I gave all the comboboxes the same event handler for their `SelectedIndexChanged event`, and set `rtb.Text = cbo.SelectedItem.ToString();` :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: But this doesn't change automatically when you switch tabpages. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't, because you haven't selected a new combobox item from the current tab's combobox, but that's fine I don't need that functionality.